# Can I annotate classes without data interactions with @Service?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, design-patterns

I have a Spring Boot application which does ETL processes and not a web application. I know that the use of services is to separate concerns and provide loose coupling but can I use it with classes that do not deal with the data being processed. I have several classes that I put in my service package and annotated it with @Service such as:

S3Service.java

```
@Service
public class S3Service {

    @Autowired
    private final AmazonS3 s3Client;

    public File downloadFile(String filename) throws Exception {
        ...
    }

    public File uploadFile(String filename) throws Exception {
        ...
    }

}
```

FileSecurityService.java

```
@Service
public FileSecurityService {

    public File decryptFile(String filename) throws Exception {
        ...
    }

    public File encryptFile(String filename) throws Exception {
        ...
    }

}
```

I did it this way because I think it makes my code cleaner but I don't think this is what services are for. I am hesitant to make them Utility classes because they are a huge part of the process. Is it a bad practice to use @Service this way? If yes, where should I put these? Thank you.

Comment: the thing with "services" that I really like is that you can inject them via a constructor, making mocking/testing a breeze. and btw `@Autowired private final AmazonS3 s3Client;` is not going to work - if you want to make it `final`, you need to inject it via the constructor.

Comment: @Eugene another reason I separated it this way is because it is very easy to test. But I am still not sure if these are "services". The FileSecurityService class does not even have any injections.

Comment: this is theory only. there are still people that think `@Service` and `@Component` is different for spring, for example. When in reality they mean exactly the same thing for the framework, but people tent to find different meanings for them

Comment: There are domain objects but where do the domain objects interact with one another? In service! You can autowire the service in controllers or anywhere. It's fine :) as long as you don't do too much in one service - or write persistence logic or controller logic in the service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing with `@Service` is that now (that you annotated it), you can inject it into different other components/beans/services, via the constructor (and Spring Boot will take care to find them and autowire correctly).

So for example, you can do:

```
@Service
public class S3Service {

      private final AmazonS3 s3Client;


      public S3Service(AmazonS3 s3Client) {
            this.s3Client = s3Client;
      }

}
```

Spring will take care to find `s3Client` bean when it needs to create the `S3Service` service.

And now in order to test `S3Service` - you can provide a `@Configuration` where `s3Client` is a mock; thus testing this is super convenient. People tent to forget just how easy spring makes this.

---

And what is a `@Service` or not is irrelevant - it is up to you and your team to decide that. A bunch of our "utilities" are services, because it is so much easier to deal with them in that manner.

Answer (score 1):

There are different types of services, depending on how you structure your application. In Spring, the annotations `@Service` and `@Repository` are inspired by the Domain Driven Design in which exist few types of services: application service, domain service, infrastructure service ... You're free to use `@Service` annotation on the top of any of these.

You can also get more specific and create custom annotations for each type of service: `@InfrastructureService`, `@ApplicationService`, `@DomainService`. If you choose to meta annotate them with `@Service` from Spring, Spring will create a bean for each class with this annotation.

For example:

```java
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Service
public @interface ApplicationService {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way because I think it makes my code cleaner but I don't think this is what services are for. -> True. It makes the code cleaner but is that a good enough argument? Spring was not just developed to make application codes look cleaner.

I am hesitant to make them Utility classes because they are a huge part of the process. -> Is this a good reason not to make it a utility class? Just because it is a big class or you have too many method in it? I don't think so.

Is it a bad practice to use @Service this way? -> IMO, creating beans just for sake of having a cleaner code is an insufficient argument to create beans and use spring framework in general.

When you code bases are big, have many packages and even more classes, sometimes it becomes difficult for a reader/reviewer to figure out where an instance of a particular class came from in the application context. That is why you see people create java classes and create the beans in the configuration classes. So there are only a few config classes where all the beans are created and injected to the application context.

Coming to your question -> should you create a bean or you should create a utility class with final keyword and static methods. IMO, you should go with the latter approach and in general you should always take into account the ideology around which spring framework was developed.